# Can rm be used to synchronize lock file checks?

Tags: linux, shell, synchronization, race-condition

I've been trying to improve a piece of shell code implementing a broken a locking mechanism.

My idea was to let only one caller through the synchronisation by calling rm on a file.

```
PIDFILE=/tmp/test.pid

flag=$PIDFILE.flag
touch $flag

if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
  ps | grep -qE '^\s*'$(cat $PIDFILE) && exit
fi

echo $$ > $PIDFILE
# this should succeed only for one process
rm $flag || exit
echo $$ > $PIDFILE
```

I've done a few concurrent calls and thrown my brain against it and haven't run into a failure.

But it is actually safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not safe.

Assume three copies of your script (A, B and C) are started simultaneously and `/tmp/test.pid` does not exist initially.

Let A and B complete the initial statements of the script:

```
PIDFILE=/tmp/test.pid

flag=$PIDFILE.flag
touch $flag

if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
  ps | grep -qE '^\s*'$(cat $PIDFILE) && exit
fi
```

Switch to A and let it run two more statements:

```
echo $$ > $PIDFILE
rm $flag || exit
```

This succeeds; `$PIDFILE` now contains A's PID.

Switch over to B and let it run the same statements. `rm` fails and so B exits, but `$PIDFILE` now contains B's PID.

Switch over to C. C has just started running, so the first thing it does is to recreate `$flag`:

```
PIDFILE=/tmp/test.pid

flag=$PIDFILE.flag
touch $flag
```

Now comes the PID check:

```
if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
  ps | grep -qE '^\s*'$(cat $PIDFILE) && exit
fi
```

This passes because `$PIDFILE` contains B's PID, but B is no longer running.

Now we get to

```
echo $$ > $PIDFILE
rm $flag || exit
```

This also passes because C has just recreated the `$flag` file.

Now we have both A and C running, racing against each other to overwrite `$PIDFILE` again.

---

Apart from that there's also a "false positive" problem:

```
if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
  ps | grep -qE '^\s*'$(cat $PIDFILE) && exit
fi
```

You might have a stale `$PIDFILE`, but the PID it contains has been reused for another process. In that case you don't get a race (and too many instances of your script), but a denial of service (too few instances of your script: 0). Your script will see the running process that just happens to have the "wrong" PID and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not safe, but maybe not for the reason you think.

Here's one possible sequence that may allow a process to pass the check while another one is still running:

1. Two processes A and B start running the script, and end up at the point before the first `echo $$ > $PIDFILE` at the same time.  For some reason, process B briefly stops here.
2. Process A writes its PID to the pidfile, successfully unlinks the flag file, writes its PID to the pidfile *again* for good measure, and continues running.
3. Now process B resumes running.  It writes its PID to pidfile, overwriting it, then fails to unlink the flag file and exits.  Process A is still running, but now the pidfile no longer contains its PID!
4. Now process C comes along, recreates the flag file, notes that the pidfile exists but contains the PID of process B (which is no longer running), and thus proceeds happily past all the checks.

Other possible sequences of events leading to the same outcome exist as well.